# Log user information on another related table if the search come empty

Tags: laravel

I have two tables Visitor and visitor_date

on Visitor, I have some inf like, name, email, and created_at to log when user was created and visitor data that has 3 fields
id, visitor_date(set to log the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), and visitor_id, this field is the FK for the visitor table.

What I am trying to achieve is logging when someone visits any builds we have and the date they visit. If I messed up with logic please let me know so I can fix it and made it different.

What I have until now is this.

A controller with a search field, that will help me with the blade file. this is the part of the controller.

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $request->search;
    $visitors = Visitor::where('email', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
        // ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
        ->get();
    return view('visitors.visitor_add', compact('visitors'));
} else {
    return view('visitors.visitor_add');
}
```

On blade I have this

A form to process the search, if email or name is not found, the page will ask if we want to add it and if the record was found, I would like to log the visit.

```
@if ($visitors->isEmpty())
    <div>
        <h2>No visitors found</h2>
        <p>Add it?</p>
    </div>
@else
    @foreach ($visitors as $visitor)
        <div class="visit-list">
            <p>{{ $visitor->email }} - Record visit?</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

How can I log the visit, using the id that was found previously?

Comment: I am not able to help you, I do not fully understand what you need, but don't use `$_GET` or `$_POST` or anything similar, you have to use `Request`.

Comment: Thanks.. What I need is to create the first entry if record for that person is not found and if its found, add an entry on table visitor_add to log how many times that person visit a place. I would like to create a link to add that record to the table without the form, it would just take the id of the visitor found and send the add command to the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forelse instead of is empty

```
@forelse ($visitors as $visitor)
<div class="visit-list">
    <p>{{ $visitor->email }}</p>
</div>
@empty
<div>
   <span>Data Not Found</span>
</div>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Hi... just to help you guys help me lol
What I need is to create the first entry if record for that person is not found and if its found, add an entry on table visitor_add to log how many times that person visit a place. I would like to create a link to add that record to the table without the form, it would just take the id of the visitor found and send the add command to the table